# How to get initial characters of a string?

Tags: php, string

I am trying to extract Initial characters of a string. I need some help with doing it in PHP.

Here are some sample strings I am working with and the results I need:

```
$String="Progress in Veterinary Science";
```

Output would be

```
// PIVS
```

Thanx!